# I can't wrap my head around this sentence from the GNU C PREPROCESSOR documentation

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, documentation, tokenize, preprocessor

[Link to the page](https://debrouxl.github.io/gcc4ti/cpp.html#SEC4)

It is in the 9th row under the "tokenization" section in the "Preprocessor overview"
It's as follows:

> The only identifier which can be considered a preprocessing keyword is `defined`.

I tried

```
#define DEFINED
```

but it works just fine.

I also asked chatGPT and searched the web for it but nothing helped.

What does this tell us in practice?
What limitations does this cause us?

Comment: Case is relevant. https://godbolt.org/z/88Prr9aav What does this tell us in practice? `error: "defined" cannot be used as a macro name`

Comment: Please copy-paste the full and complete paragraph into your question. Make the question *self-contained*, without needs for external links.

Comment: *"I also asked chatGPT"* ChatGPT in its current state is not a reliable source of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that C is a case-sensitive language, so `DEFINED` and `defined` mean different things. What the text refers to is the special identifier `defined` only valid inside pre-processor macros. Usage is like this:

```c
#if defined(__STDC__) && (__STDC__VERSION == 201710L)
  puts("This C compiler is up to date.");
#endif
```

This is equivalent to:

```c
#ifdef __STDC__
  #if (__STDC__VERSION == 201710L)
    puts("This C compiler is up to date.");
  #endif
#endif
```

As we can see, the benefit of `define` is that it allows simpler pre-processor checks without resorting to multiple nested `#if`/`#ifdef`. Suppose we want to check of a compiler is following standard C and also supports VLA:

```c
#if defined(__STDC__) && !defined(__STDC_NO_VLA__)
  puts("This compiler is useful");
#else
  puts("This compiler is useless");
#endif
```

That's a whole lot more convenient code with no code repetition, compared to this mess:

```c
#ifdef __STDC__
  #ifndef __STDC_NO_VLA__
    puts("This compiler is useful");
  #else
    puts("This compiler is useless");
  #endif
#else
  puts("This compiler is useless");
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

> I tried
>
> ```
> #define DEFINED
> ```
>
> but it works just fine.

C is case-sensitive. `defined` is not same as `DEFINED`.

> What does this tell us in practice? What limitations does this cause us?

`defined` keyword is usable only in expressions of `#if` and `#elif` preprocessing directives.

In theory you could create ambiguous code like:

```
#define defined
#if defined defined
    // Is this line included or not?
#endif
```

Thought more likely you get a compiler error.

In practical world this is not an issue. Just don't define `defined` preprocessing symbol. This comparable to not being able to create variables named `if` or `while`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you can write either:

```c
#ifdef MACRO
```

Or:

```c
#if defined MACRO
```

So you can't name a macro defined because it's a keyword.

Comment: Strictly speaking it is not a keyword but a pre-processor "operator" as the standard calls it.